# How to throw a 400 bad request from a symfony controller?

Tags: php, symfony

I have set up a very simple stub of a Symfony 3.3 controller whose main action looks looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/pair-gallery/{id}")
 */
public function indexAction(Int $id)
{
    $output = [];
    return new JsonResponse($output);
}
```

When I give it a string as an argument in the url (rather than an integer), I currently get a 500 error. That's not horrible, but it's not exactly what I want.

How do I tell Symfony to send back a 400 ("Bad Request") response code instead?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can simply throw a exception that get automatically transformed to a HTTP 400 response:

```
throw new BadRequestHttpException('Message');
```

If you want to be specific about the thrown http error code (maybe you want to throw an obscure error code like 418) you can pass it as the third parameter:

```
throw new BadRequestHttpException('Message', null, 418);
```

Comment: Is there a good way to do this without throwing an exception (and thus triggering monolog)? In my project I currently throw the exception, but it results in an awful lot of errors in the log that I wouldn't really consider errors.

Answer (score 12):

you can specify the return code like this:

```
return new JsonResponse($output, 400);
```

Comment: Instead of hardcoding magic numbers like "400", it's a good idea to use Symfony's own constants: `JsonResponse($output, JsonResponse::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);`

Answer (score 3):

For those who got here solving same issue, but for Symfony 5

```
$response = new JsonResponse($output, 400);  

return $response->send(); // Send it !
```

[Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html#symfony-response-object)